# Security of displaying ID's in Hidden fields

Tags: c#, security, logic

I am trying to understand what is the proper way to handle the following scenario.  I wish to learn more about what is acceptable to be passed on a page in terms of security.

Lets take a tournament scenario.  We have a list of teams that are signed up which are displayed on the page.  In order to report result of a game, you have to click on the team and then select win or lose.  Then this is posted back to the server which then in return records it in the database.

The dilemma is to know which team you have clicked and for which game.  As there are many rounds, 1 team can be displayed many times.  As such I need to have a hidden field on the page that has the ID of the team and ID of the game so that I can record the result.

What I am wondering is, how secure it is for me to create a hidden field that holds my ID.  Is there a better way to handle such a scenario?  Am I giving out too much information to the hacker if I print out the ID in the hidden field?

Some of the answers I have found through my research say that it "may" be ok as long as I authorize the request.  So the user who is reporting the score has enough privileges to report that score.  However I wished to ask some of the experts here at stackoverflow to further support that research.

EDIT:

This is for a web application.  If printing out the ID is a no go, how else would I determine which team was selected for which round?  I need to have some sort of an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an UI pattern like MVVM or MVC **in a desktop application**, sensitive information should be kept in your model or controller. There is no need to abuse view components for (temporary) data storage. While there is no obvious way to get the contents of a hidden field in a desktop application, there may be tools that can accomplish this.

If we are talking about a web application here, this is **absolutely a no-go**, as everyone can print out the html source code and disclose sensitive information. The same rules as above apply - sensitive information must not be delivered into view components.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID is included when you do the POST back to the server, then that will reveal the ID more than holding it in a hidden field will. I can hit F12 in Chrome/Firefox/IE and see all the data in a POST request.

If you already have user authentication, then worry about controlling permissions for what an authorized user can do.

Comment: Thanks, your question is a little bit more precise now. If every visible team has an unique identifier, is it considered sensitive at all? Why shouldn't someone know a team's id?

Comment: it is sensitive in the fact that is an ID from the database.  When I go back to report a score and write a record in the database, I have to identify the correct record that needs to be updated and that comes from the unique ID I spoke of before.  Or at least that is the only way I can think of to do this.

Comment: Data is only sensitive if someone can do something harmful with it. Can someone do something harmful if they know the ID of a team?

Comment: On top of my head, maybe use that ID to report a score for a different tournament if they can bypass my logic.  So lets say yes it is sensitive.

Comment: You can't get around using some kind of identifier. If you don't use an ID, then you'll be sending a team name, or something else, all of which will identify the team and can be read by watching the HTTP traffic. I'd concentrate my efforts to make sure they cannot bypass my logic.

Comment: So then you are agreeing that I should print out the ID in the hidden field and ensure my authentication and authorization are solid.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Don't worry about people seeing the ID as long as your security is solid.